orientation preserving map between manifolds
Let $h: S^n \to S^n$ be a differentiable map, defined by $h(x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1}) = (-x_1,\ldots,-x_k,x_{k+1},\ldots,x_{n+1})$. I want to prove that $h$ preserve orientation of the sphere iff $k$ is even.
I know that $\{(U_N,\phi_N), (U_S,\phi_S)\}$ is an atlas on $S^n$ (stereographic projections). Now, to prove that the $h$ preserve orientation, I need to show that $\operatorname{det}(J(\phi_j\circ h \circ \phi_k^{-1})) > 0$ for any $j, k \in \{N, S\}$? Or because $S^n$ is embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ it results that $T_pS^n \subset T_p \mathbb{R^{n+1}}$, so I can calculate the determinant of jacobian matrix of $h$ directly in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and check for that?
I may have said some things wrong, but please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks!

Do you know the language of volume forms?

@Didier Let's say that I have a minimum knowledge about them

I'm writing an answer using that language. It is quite elementary, but still can be confusing if you're not familiar with it.

@Didier please write it. I will try to understand. Also, my approach with $\operatorname{det}(J(\phi_j\circ h \circ \phi_k^{-1})) > 0$ is good or not?

Your approach should work as well. I'm just preaching my "abstract-nonsense" chapel :)

$h$ is actually the restriction of a (smooth) linear map $H\colon\Bbb R^{n+1}\to\Bbb R^{n+1}$, whose determinant is obviously $(-1)^k$.
$S^n$ inherits an orientation as the boundary of $B^{n+1}\subset\Bbb R^{n+1}$ (see, for example, Guillemin and Pollack): If $N(x)=x$ is the unit outward normal to the sphere, then $v_1,\dots,v_n$ gives a positively-oriented basis for $T_xS^n$ by definition if and only if $N(x),v_1,\dots,v_n$ is a positively-oriented basis for $\Bbb R^{n+1}$. Now note that the outward normal at $y=H(x)$ is likewise $y=H(x)$, so $H$ maps $N(x),v_1,\dots,v_n$ to $N(H(x)),Hv_1,\dots,Hv_n$. This means that $Hv_1,\dots,Hv_n$ is a positively-oriented basis at $H(x)$ if and only if $H$ is an orientation-preserving map on $\Bbb R^{n+1}$, i.e., if and only if $k$ is even.
Regarding @Didier's answer, I would prefer to work with actual differential forms. The volume $n$-form on a smooth hypersurface of $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ (see many entries on this site) is given by
$$\sigma(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{N+1} (-1)^{i-1} N_i(x) dx_1\wedge \dots \wedge \widehat{dx_i} \wedge\dots\wedge dx_{n+1},$$ where $N_i$ is the $i^{\text{th}}$ component of the unit outward normal $N$ and the $\widehat{dx_i}$ indicates that this term has been omitted. For the sphere, of course, $N(x)=x$; when $n=3$, for example, we have $\sigma = x_1\,dx_2\wedge dx_3 - x_2\,dx_1\wedge dx_3 + x_3\,dx_1\wedge dx_2$.
When we pull $\sigma$ back by $H$, we get $H^*x_i = -x_i$ for $1\le i\le k$ and $H^*x_i = x_i$ for $k+1\le i\le n+1$. Thus, $H^*dx_i=-dx_i$ for $1\le i\le k$ and $H^*dx_i = dx_i$ for $k+1\le i\le n+1$. You can easily check, then, that $H^*\sigma = (-1)^k\sigma$, and so $H$ is orientation-preserving if and only if $k$ is even.

I will present a proof using the language of volume forms.
Considering the embedding $S^n \subset \Bbb R^{n+1}$, one easily verifies that for $x\in S^n$, one has $T_xS^n = \{x\}^{\perp}$, and thus $\Bbb R^{n+1} = \Bbb R x \oplus T_xS^n$.
Define $\omega \in \Omega^n(S^n)$ given by
$$
\forall x \in S^n, \forall v_1,\ldots,v_n \in T_x S^n,\quad \omega_x(v_1,\ldots,v_n) = \det(x,v_1,\ldots,v_n),
$$
where the determinant is taken with respect to the canonical basis of $\Bbb R^{n+1}$.
Then $\omega$ is a nowhere vanishing differential form of degree $n$ on $S^n$, and thus defines an orientation.
Up to considering $-\omega$, we assume that $\omega$ defines the chosen orientation of $S^n$.
Let $h_k \colon S^n \to S^n$ be given by $h_k(x^1,\ldots,x^n) = (-x^1,\ldots,-x^k,x^{k+1},\ldots,x^n)$.
Notice that $h_k$ is the restriction of a linear map which we still denote $h_k$, so that its differential at any point is given by $h_k$.
Then, for $x\in S^n$ and $v_1,\ldots,v_n \in T_xS^n$, one has
\begin{align}
(h_k^*\omega)_x(v_1,\ldots,v_n)
&=\omega_{h_k(x)}(d_xh_k(v_1),\ldots,d_xh_k(v_n)) \\
&= \det(h_k(x),h_k(v_1),\ldots,h_k(v_n)) \\
&= \det\begin{pmatrix}
-x^1 & -(v_1)^1 &  \cdots & -(v_n)^1 \\
\vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
-x^k & -(v_1)^k & \cdots & -(v_n)^k \\
x^{k+1} & (v_1)^{k+1} &\cdots & (v_n)^{k+1} \\
\vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
x^{n+1} & (v_1)^{n+1} & \cdots & (v_n)^{n+1}
\end{pmatrix} \\
&=(-1)^k \det\begin{pmatrix}
x^1 & (v_1)^1 &  \cdots & (v_n)^1 \\
\vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
x^k & (v_1)^k & \cdots & (v_n)^k \\
x^{k+1} & (v_1)^{k+1} &\cdots & (v_n)^{k+1} \\
\vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
x^{n+1} & (v_1)^{n+1} & \cdots & (v_n)^{n+1}
\end{pmatrix} \\
&= (-1)^k\det(x,v_1,\ldots,v_n) \\
&= (-1)^k \omega_x(v_1,\ldots,v_n)
\end{align}
where superscripts denote the coefficients in the canonical basis of $\Bbb R^{n+1}$.
It follows that
$$
h_k^* \omega = (-1)^k \omega.
$$
Hence,
\begin{align}
h_k \text{ preserves the orientation }
& \iff h_k^* \omega \text{ defines the same orientation than } \omega \\
& \iff h_k^*\omega \text{ is a positive multiple of } \omega \\
& \iff (-1)^k > 0 \\
& \iff k \text{ is even.}
\end{align}
As a by-product, this shows that the antipodal maps is orientation-preserving if and only if $n$ is odd, and this idea can be used to show that the real projective space is orientable if and only if it is odd dimensional.
